# 'object Promise' is returned on async/await call

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, fetch-api

I want to fetch data for a List of Cards that also contain Images due another API call that I try to fetch. But all I get is a Promise Object.

Please be aware that 'read the documentation' responses are not helpful at all. Thanks.

Here is where I render:

```
             <Row>
                {this.state.data.map(d => {
                    return (
                        <Col>
                            <Card style={{width: '10rem'}}>
                                <Card.Img variant="top" src={this.getImage(d.id)}/>
                                <Card.Body>
                                    <Card.Title>
                                        {d.name}
                                    </Card.Title>
                                    <Card.Subtitle>
                                        ID : {d.id}
                                    </Card.Subtitle>
                                    <Card.Text>
                                        {d.origin}
                                    </Card.Text>
                                </Card.Body>
                            </Card>
                        </Col>
                    )
                })}
            </Row>
```

After DOM-Renders the Result is:

```
<img class="card-img-top" src="[object Promise]">
```

and now finally my fetch-function getImage(id):

```
getImage = async id => {
    return await fetch('https://api.thedogapi.com/v1/images/search?breed_id=' + id, {
        mode: 'cors',
        headers: {
            'x-api-key': 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
        }
    });
}
```

So when I try to find a solution it always seems that the regular problem is **missing async and await** in the fetch what I do have as you can see.

So what am I doing wrong? I also added then(). to my fetch of course but the result is the same:

```
getImage = async id => {
return await fetch('https://api.thedogapi.com/v1/images/search?breed_id=' + id, {
    mode: 'cors',
    headers: {
        'x-api-key': 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
    }
}).then(r => r.json()).then(d => d[0]['url']);
}
```

It does show me the data in console by console.log(...)-calls

Comment: Could you try instead of `return await x` put it in a variable and return the variable after awaiting, so `const x = await ... ; return x;`.

Comment: I did, but the result is the same, of course

Comment: The callback to `map` needs to be `async` and you need to `await getImage(…)`, although I have no idea if that's even possible in JSX. If not, you need to resolve all the images outside of the JSX block and pass in a regular array of URL's.

Comment: I do get your point in changing the place of async/await, but it neither helps or works, as you thought

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```js
getImage = async id => {
return await fetch('https://api.thedogapi.com/v1/images/search?breed_id=' + id, {
    mode: 'cors',
    headers: {
        'x-api-key': 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
    }
}).then(r => r.json()).then(d => return d[0]['url']);
}
```

```js
Promise.all(this.state.data.map(item=>getImage(item.id))).then((resolve)=>{
  imageArray = resolve
})
```

then

```
<Row>
  {this.state.data.map((d, index) => {
    return (
      <Col>
        <Card style={{ width: "10rem" }}>
          <Card.Img variant="top" src={imageArray[i]} />
          <Card.Body>
            <Card.Title>{d.name}</Card.Title>
            <Card.Subtitle>ID : {d.id}</Card.Subtitle>
            <Card.Text>{d.origin}</Card.Text>
          </Card.Body>
        </Card>
      </Col>
    );
  })}
</Row>;
```

Comment: I do not understand this answer, you just copy-pasted half of my code and added a Promise.all()-call without any explaination and further where I should put it

Comment: i do not speak/read chinese